# Database Link error ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Tags: oracle, dblink

I am currently accessing/connecting to a remote database through VPN and I have no issues querying on the remote database. I want to create a db-link to connect my local db to the remote database in order to join certain tables. Sadly, I am getting error ORA-12545.

This is my db-link code:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK DB_LINK
CONNECT TO REMOTE_USER_NAME
IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=test_SID))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOST_NAME.com)(PORT=1521)))'
```

I don't have an Oracle client installed on my machine so I am using the full description. There are no issue accessing both our db and the remote db without an Oracle client installed so I assume this is not the problem.

My ping to the remote address returned `TTL expired in transit` even though the VPN is connected. This seems a bit weird but I am not entirely sure if this is the problem.

I must be missing a crucial step. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the remote listener?

Comment: Does hostname.com resolve from your end of the VPN? If it's an intranet-only address it might not. Did you ping that FQDN or the IP? If you can definitely route to the host IP via VPN you could use that in the DB link instead of the name?

Comment: @AlexPoole Initially, I pinged the FQDN. I just pinged the IP and it is showing as "time out". Ran the new db-link with IP as host and getting error TNS connect timeout. Not sure if it's an intranet-only address. The last guy here did mentioned something about our db running in intranet.

Comment: So how do you currently access the remote DB over the VPN? From a client running locally, or are you connecting to a server inside the VPN and accessing the DB from there?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have to log in to a web page(by pulse secure)which will create a secure connection and run Juniper(our vpn software). Then I can log into the remote db using SQL Developer.

Comment: OK, is SQL Developer running via Citrix Metaframe or similar, so it is also inside the intranet; or locally on your PC? If the latter, how is the connection defined in SQL Developer? And I suppose I should check if your local database is on the same machine as SQL Developer, or in a VM or something?

Comment: SQL Developer is installed locally on my PC and our machines have a shared connection with the local db which is literally in the next room. My SQL Dev configuration- connection type:Basic, Role: Default, and I am using Service name instead of SID. I tried using service_name in my db-link, it wasn't working.

Comment: Right, but Juniper will only send traffic from your PC over the VPN, not from anything else on your LAN, right? The machine with the local DB can see your PC but it can't bridge through that to the VPN. It may be possible to circumvent that but I'd check whether you are allowed to. VPN owners tend not to be keen on anything that effectively breaches the security the VPN is there to enforce.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you. That makes sense.